# How to add a smooth motion to the parallax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am a huge fan of Parallax and i see this code which is amazing
But the point is how can we add a smooth effect to it like as soon as i stop mouse moment it won't stop suddenly.
[Here is the Codepen](https://codepen.io/Beardwig/pen/VKAzpp)

Thanks

Some Code

```
$(function() {
  var isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 768px)");
  var moveForce = 30; // max popup movement in pixels
  var rotateForce = 5; // max popup rotation in deg
  $(".wrap").mousemove(function(e) {
    var docX = $(this).outerWidth();
    var docY = $(this).outerHeight();

    var moveX = (e.pageX - docX / 2) / (docX / 2) * -moveForce;
    var moveY = (e.pageY - docY / 2) / (docY / 2) * -moveForce;

    var rotateY = (e.pageX / docX * rotateForce * 2) - rotateForce;
    var rotateX = -((e.pageY / docY * rotateForce * 2) - rotateForce);

    $('.wrap').css({
      '-moz-transform': 'rotateX(' + rotateX + 'deg' + ') rotateY(' + rotateY + 'deg' + ') translateZ(0)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'rotateX(' + rotateX + 'deg' + ') rotateY(' + rotateY + 'deg' + ') translateZ(0)',
      '-ms-transform': 'rotateX(' + rotateX + 'deg' + ') rotateY(' + rotateY + 'deg' + ') translateZ(0)',
      '-o-transform': 'rotateX(' + rotateX + 'deg' + ') rotateY(' + rotateY + 'deg' + ') translateZ(0)',
      'transform': 'rotateX(' + rotateX + 'deg' + ') rotateY(' + rotateY + 'deg' + ') translateZ(0)',
    });
  });
  if (isMobile.matches) {
    function onDeviceMotion(event) {
      rotateForce = 10; // max popup rotation in deg
      var accel = event.accelerationIncludingGravity;

      var docX = $(this).outerWidth();
      var docY = $(this).outerHeight();

      var accelX = ((accel.x + 10) / 20) * docX;
      var accelY = ((accel.y + 10) / 20) * docY;

      var moveX = (accelX - docX) / (docX) * -moveForce;
      var moveY = (accelY - docY) / (docY) * -moveForce;

      var rotateY = -((accelX / docX * rotateForce * 2) - rotateForce);
      var rotateX = -((accelY / docY * rotateForce * 2) - rotateForce);

      $('.').css({
        '-moz-transform': 'rotateX(' + rotateX + 'deg' + ') rotateY(' + rotateY + 'deg' + ') translateZ(0)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotateX(' + rotateX + 'deg' + ') rotateY(' + rotateY + 'deg' + ') translateZ(0)',
        '-ms-transform': 'rotateX(' + rotateX + 'deg' + ') rotateY(' + rotateY + 'deg' + ') translateZ(0)',
        '-o-transform': 'rotateX(' + rotateX + 'deg' + ') rotateY(' + rotateY + 'deg' + ') translateZ(0)',
        'transform': 'rotateX(' + rotateX + 'deg' + ') rotateY(' + rotateY + 'deg' + ') translateZ(0)',
      });
    };
    window.addEventListener("devicemotion", onDeviceMotion, false);
  }
});
```

Comment: I think it's because of '.wrap {transition: transform 100ms linear;}'.

Comment: @JS KIM Yes it works well. thanks JS. Set your answer here and let me ive you the full credit by accepting it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad to be helpful.

CSS - transition property : https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/CSS/transition